# How do you find the average of a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

So let's say I have this dictionary

```
{'Taylor Swift': ['Kanye West']}
```

I would expect 1.0 from this as there is one value (which is 'Kanye West') divided by one key (which is 'Taylor Swift') to get the average of 1.0.

And let's say I have this dictionary

```
{'Taylor Swift': ['Kanye West', 'Elvis Presley'], 'Adam Sandler': ['Johnny Depp', 'Tom Hanks']}
```

I would expect the average of 2.0 from this as there are 4 values divided by 2 keys.

This is the code I have tried:

```
average = 0
sum = 0
for n in data:
    sum = sum + n
average = sum / len(data)
```

I have tried many other ways too through online search and the common error I get is this:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: By "average" do you mean the average length of the values in your dictionary (i.e., the average number of items in the lists)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
average = 0
sum = 0
for key in data.keys():
    sum = sum +len(data[key])
average = sum / len(data)
```

Answer (score 7):

Taking "average" as "the average number of items in the lists", you can achieve it as:

```
average_length = sum( len(v) for v in data.values() ) / len(data)
```

The first part adds together the length of all the lists you have as dictionary values, while `len(data)` is the number of key:value pair you have in the dictionary.

Comment: You can use float(len(data)) for getting floating values results

Comment: For python 3 that is not necessary (that was my original assumption), although I should probably add the import of division from __future__ to make the code compatible with both python versions

Answer (score 1):

```
 average = 0
 sum = 0
 for v in data.values():
      sum = sum + len(v)

 average = sum / len(data.keys())
```

Answer (score 1):

Use simple for loop

```
var= {'Taylor Swift': ['Kanye West', 'Elvis Presley'], 'Adam Sandler': 
['Johnny Depp', 'Tom Hanks']}

sum = 0
for value in var.values():
    sum = len(value)+sum

Average = sum/len(var)
print(Average)
```

**Output**

```
2.0
```

Comment: `list` is a type name in python, you shouldn't use it as a variable name (and, besides that, probably `list` is not a good name for a dictionary anyway..)

Comment: ohh sorry i just did it for his reference .but thanks for telling

Answer (score 0):

Could use reduce here too:

```
from functools import reduce
data = {'Taylor Swift': ['Kanye West', 'Elvis Presley'], 'Adam Sandler': ['Johnny Depp', 'Tom Hanks']}
reduce((lambda x, y: len(x)+len(y)), data .values()) / len(data )
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the length of values first and divide it by the length of keys.

```
sum(len(i) for i in data.values())/float(len(data.keys()))
```

and this gives the same result as well,

```
sum(len(i) for i in x.values())/float(len(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
#some dictionary
d={'Taylor Swift': ['Kanye',' West', 'Elvis',' Presley','l'], 'Adam Sandler': ['Johnny',' Depp', 'Tom',' Hanks']}
#Sum function gets the sum of all values in dictionary
#Len function gets the total number of keys in dictionary
#Multiplying with 1.0 to get exact division, else import division function from _future_ library 
avg = sum(len(v) for v in d.itervalues())*1.0/len(d)
print avg
```